# What are the hearts for?

Tags: wario-land

When I am going through levels and hitting item blocks, sometimes hearts pop out. I collect them, but I can't really see a purpose for them.

What are the hearts for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to coins in the Mario games, collecting 100 hearts provides a one-up. Collecting a large heart provides THREE extra lives.